# Имеет ли смысл размещать медиа на .onion-сайте в даркнэте, либо можно ссылаться и на лайтвеб?

Tags: html, веб-программирование, hosting, tor, onion

Всем привет!
Имеется ресурс в лайт вебе (обычном интернете), размещённый на нескольких серверах и поддоменах. Условно назовём сервера ***A*** (основной, с кодом) и ***B*** (вспомогательный, с фото и видео), а домены назовём, соответственно, ***website.com*** и ***media.website.com***.
У сайта ***website.com*** имеется зеркало в даркнэте (которое также размещено на сервере ***A*** и ссылается на ту же папку), пусть это будет ***website.onion***. Сайт ***media.website.com***, находящийся на сервере ***B*** может иметь (но пока не имеет) зеркало ***mediawebsite.onion***
На данный момент все фото, размещённые на сайте ***website.onion*** имеют формат:

```
<img src="https://media.website.com/image.jpeg" alt="" />
```

Разумеется, даже если ресурс ***media.website.com*** заблокирован в стране пользователя. то всё прекрасно загружается через сеть TOR.
Вопрос состоит в следующем: имеет ли смысл преобразовать все ссылки на медиафайлы на сайте ***website.onion*** с ***media.website.com/...*** в ***mediawebsite.onion/...*** и если да, то какой?
Спасибо!

Comment: Я не очень в курсе, как работает TOR, но: если браузер загрузит картинку из обычного интернета (или даже просто отошлёт запрос на загрузку), его провайдер сможет узнать, что юзер посещал ваш сайт в даркнете, верно?

Comment: По идее, нет, т.к. пользователь уже использует сеть Tor и его подключение защищено (даже есть он посещает обычные сайты)

Comment: Вот дискуссия по теме: https://gitlab.torproject.org/legacy/trac/-/issues/13747. У TOR Browser'а есть настройка `OnionTrafficOnly` (но я не сильно разбираюсь в том, для чего именно она нужна).

Comment: Да, спасибо! Это то, что нужно! Размести, пожалуйста, как ответ, чтобы я мог за него проголосовать и отметить, как верый

Comment: Ну, я не совсем понимаю, каким образом ссылка ответила на ваш вопрос :) Объясните? Я и правда не совсем в теме.

Comment: Надстройка в браузере "OnionTrafficOnly" явно говорит о том, что будет приниматься только ".onion" трафик. Из чего следует, что у некоторых пользователей она, скорее всего, включена, а значит они не увидят фото. Кроме того, на другом ресурсе мне ответили, что использование "mixed" контента приведёт к замедлению загрузки сайта, т.к., грубо говоря, придётся выходить из сети Tor после загрузки основного контента, чтобы затем загрузить фото

Comment: Ага, понял логику, сейчас напишу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По результатам обсуждения в комментариях выяснилось следующее.

Некоторые пользователи считают, что ссылки из onion-сайта в открытый интернет менее безопасны, чем ссылки на другие onion-ресурсы (подобно тому, как https-сайты не должны бы использовать http-контент). TOR Browser даже имеет настройку `OnionTrafficOnly`, позволяющую предотвратить загрузку контента из «открытого» интернета.

Таким образом, для тех, у кого эта настройка включена, изображения грузиться не будут (и по их мнению, ваш сайт будет менее безопасным).

Поскольку преобразовать ссылки — не очень большая работа, я бы именно так и сделал.

Релевантное обсуждение: https://gitlab.torproject.org/legacy/trac/-/issues/13747